# How to load Chrome Extensions in QtWebengine

Tags: c++, qt, google-chrome-extension, qtwebengine

Is there a way by which we can load/install chrome extension in QtWebengine based browsers.

Comment: I tried to test how its possible but in every try this qtwebengine crashed :) maybe win10 issue but sorry no result from my side. I would suggest to use nwjs or electron they look more stable.

Answer (score 1):

This is still not currently possible (see [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51185) and [this other one](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61676))